# How to connect to mqtt broker using libmosquitto and SSL/TLS in C++

Tags: c++, ssl, mqtt, libmosquitto

I'm trying to subscribe to an mqtt broker which uses SSL/TLS to authenticate clients.
I use [**libmosquitto**](https://mosquitto.org/api/files/mosquitto-h.html) to do that.

I run this code to perform a subscription

```cpp
#include <csignal>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <mosquitto.h>

#define WITH_AUTHENTICATION

#define MQTT_HOST       "exmaple.com"
#define MQTT_PORT       8883
#define TARGET_USER     "use"
#define TARGET_PW       "password"
#define TARGET_TOPIC    "/example-topic"
#define CERTIFICATE     "/home/luca/TRIALS/tryMqttS/cert.pem"

using namespace std;

static int run  = 1;




void signalHandler (int s) {
    run = 0;
}




void messageCallback (struct mosquitto *mosq, void *obj, const struct mosquitto_message *message) {
    bool match  = 0;
    cout << "got message  " << (char *) message->payload << "  from topic  " << message->topic << endl;
}




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    uint8_t reconnect       = true;
    string clientID         = "mosquitto_client_" + to_string (getpid());
    struct mosquitto *mosq  = nullptr;
    int resCode             = 0;

    signal (SIGINT, signalHandler);
    signal (SIGTERM, signalHandler);

    mosquitto_lib_init ();

    mosq    = mosquitto_new (clientID.c_str(), true, 0);

    if(mosq){
        mosquitto_message_callback_set (mosq, messageCallback);

#ifdef WITH_AUTHENTICATION
        cout << "Pw set result:             " << mosquitto_strerror (mosquitto_username_pw_set  (mosq, TARGET_USER, TARGET_PW)) << endl;
        cout << "Tls insecure set result:   " << mosquitto_strerror (mosquitto_tls_insecure_set (mosq, false)) << endl;
        cout << "Tls opts set result:       " << mosquitto_strerror (mosquitto_tls_opts_set     (mosq, 1, NULL, NULL)) << endl;
        cout << "Tls set result:            " << mosquitto_strerror (mosquitto_tls_set (mosq, CERTIFICATE, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, /*pw_cb * */ nullptr)) << endl;
#endif


        cout << "Connection result:         " << mosquitto_strerror (mosquitto_connect (mosq, MQTT_HOST, MQTT_PORT, 60)) << endl;
        cout << "Subscription result:       " << mosquitto_strerror (mosquitto_subscribe (mosq, NULL, TARGET_TOPIC, 0)) << endl;


        while (run) {
            resCode = mosquitto_loop (mosq, 20, 1);
            if (resCode) {
                cout << "ERROR:  " << mosquitto_strerror (resCode) << "  (" << resCode << ")\n";
                sleep(1);
                mosquitto_reconnect (mosq);
            }
        }

        mosquitto_destroy (mosq);
    }

    mosquitto_lib_cleanup ();

    return 0;
}
```

but the output is every time the same:

```
Connection result:    0
Subscription result:  0
ERROR:  The connection was lost.  (7)
ERROR:  The connection was lost.  (7)
ERROR:  The connection was lost.  (7)
ERROR:  The connection was lost.  (7)
ERROR:  The connection was lost.  (7)
ERROR:  The connection was lost.  (7)
ERROR:  The connection was lost.  (7)
ERROR:  The connection was lost.  (7)
ERROR:  The connection was lost.  (7)
ERROR:  The connection was lost.  (7)
ERROR:  The connection was lost.  (7)
```

Using an external tool (e.g. **mqttfx**) and using the same authentication credentials, the subscription is good and I can receive messages published on topic.

How can I perform the subscription correctly? Are there some missing settings?

Comment: What do the broker logs say when you try to connect?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't access to machine where broker is running

Comment: Your code says `localhost` so why don't you have access to to the broker logs?

Comment: Yes but I cannot write the real IP address

Comment: Fine then use something like `example.com` as `localhost` has very specific meaning (it behaves differently to any external device) and implies a bunch of things which are not the case here.

Comment: The posted code is C++, not C.  Please remove the 'c' tag from the question

Answer (score 0):

For subscribing `MQTT Broker`needs to be running at your specified host and port. In your code you're using `exmaple.com`(I think you meant `example.com`) as `MQTT Broker` host. There is no `Broker` running on this host. So it fails to connect. Use `test.mosquitto.org` which hosts publicly available `MQTT Broker`.

Or you can run your own `MQTT Broker` on your computer at port `8883`. Then you can connect using `localhost`